Create a Pivot Table Using xlwings
I am trying to automatize the creation of pivot table using xlwings. Here is a random piece of code I created which is supposed to create a pivot table, but I am getting an error at the line where pivot_table is created. I cannot go past this line, and my debugger exits immediately.
Any idea what is going on?
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import constants

def get_pivot():
    # Create a sample DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=100),
        'Product': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 100),
        'Region': np.random.choice(['North', 'South', 'East', 'West'], 100),
        'Sales': np.random.randint(100, 1000, 100)
    })

    # Start an Excel application
    wb = xw.Book(path_to_excel)
    ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

    # Clear the contents of the worksheet
    ws.clear_contents()
    
    # Write the DataFrame to Excel
    ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df
    
    # Get the data range
    data_range = ws.range('A1').expand()

    # Create PivotCache
    pivot_cache = wb.api.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=constants.PivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData=data_range.api) # , Version=constants.PivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14) 
    
    pivot_table = pivot_cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=ws.range('F2'), TableName='SalesPivot')

    # Configure pivot table fields
    pivot_table = ws.api.PivotTables("SalesPivot")

    # Configure the pivot table fields
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Date').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Date').NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Product').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Region').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Sales').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField

    # Set Data Field
    sales_field = pivot_table.PivotFields('Sales')
    sales_field.Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    sales_field.Function = xw.constants.ConsolidationFunction.xlSum
          
    # Save the workbook
    print("Pivot table created successfully!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xw.serve()

I debugged using the xlwings debugger, the code always exit the debugger each time the line pivot table is processed.
I modified the line where I added
Version=constants.PivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14

but it does not work neither:
pivot_cache = wb.api.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=constants.PivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData=data_range.api, Version=constants.PivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14)


I think your just having an issue with the table location value.
The following example incorporates your dataframe and code to create a Pivot Table in the one command rather than using the two though if you wish to do those steps separately you can do that. 
The code uses a context manager which will wrap up the Excel instances after the Excel workbook is saved.
Can be placed in a function if that is your requirement.
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import constants
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


path_to_excel = 'PivotTable.xlsx'

with xw.App(visible=True) as xl:
    # Create a sample DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=100),
        'Product': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 100),
        'Region': np.random.choice(['North', 'South', 'East', 'West'], 100),
        'Sales': np.random.randint(100, 1000, 100)
    })

    # Start an Excel application
    wb = xl.books.open(path_to_excel)
    ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

    # Clear the contents of the worksheet
    ws.clear_contents()
    # Write the DataFrame to Excel
    ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df

    # Get the data range
    data_range = ws.range('A1').expand()

    # Set the Pivot Table Name
    table_name = "SalesPivot"

    # Set the Pivot Table Destination
    table_location = ws.range('F2')

    # Create Pivot Table
    pivot_table = wb.api.PivotCaches().Create(
        SourceType=constants.PivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
        SourceData=data_range.api).CreatePivotTable(
        TableDestination=table_location.api,
        TableName=table_name)

    # Configure the pivot table fields
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Date').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Date').NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Product').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Region').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField
    pivot_table.PivotFields('Sales').Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField

    # Set Data Field
    sales_field = pivot_table.PivotFields('Sales')
    sales_field.Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
    sales_field.Function = xw.constants.ConsolidationFunction.xlSum

    # Save the workbook
    wb.save(path_to_excel)
    print("Pivot table created successfully!")



Example Output Sheet

